# Socket android client PC server

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

I have problem to connect my android client to my PC Server
here there are the codes

-->PC SERVER:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{

   ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(4444);

   System.out.println("Waiting for clients to connect...");

   while (true)
   {
      Socket s = server.accept();
      InetAddress clientAddress = s.getInetAddress();
      System.out.println("Incoming connection from: " + clientAddress.getHostName() + "[" + clientAddress.getHostAddress() + "]");

      s.close();
   }
}
```

}

--->ANDROID CLIENT:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

Button b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            try {
                 Socket client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4444); //connect to server

                 client.close();   //closing the connection

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });

}
```

When on my android device i click the button in my server program(PC) doesn't view device connect...why? i've tried to insert

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

into my AndroidManifest but when i click on button program crash
Android device and PC are connected to same network(router DSL).

Help me please

Comment: i don't know what ip address need to insert into 

    Socket client = new Socket("", 4444);

my android device and pc are connected into same local network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10.0.2.2 is an address that is used by your app running in an emulator to connect with a server running on your pc. The emulator is on the same pc. If you use a real devive you have to use the (W)LAN address of your pc which is in the same WLAN as your device. Often something like 192.168.0.12. Find out with ipconfig.

Answer (score 0):

The address you are using is `10.0.2.2`, which is [non routable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-routable_ip_address) as private.

You should use an address that your device can resolve. Either a DNS name published in a DNS accessible from your phone (so a public one) or a routable IP. Your server should be reachable from the public network, which is unlikely to be the case of your PC unless you have specifically took care of that - I am not sure of what you mean by this:

> Android device and PC are connected to same network(router DSL)

Please have a look at the exception that is thrown on phone side and edit your post with the resulting stack trace. It will help to dig into this further.

Answer (score 0):

Your socket declaration should be as follow :

```
Socket client = new Socket(10.0.2.2, 4444); //Quotes removed
```